# One company wants to make an offer, but I want to see if company B is interested first

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-offer

**The Situation**

Company A liked me a lot and wants to make an offer. Its a great opportunity, but I'm really interested in company B for which I have an interview this afternoon. I've been very transparent about my options to everybody thus far. My recruiter for Company A wants to know the timetable for Company B and my interest level in comparison to his client.

**My Dilemma**

My current job is ending in two weeks, so I really need a job. And I've had a number of previous companies turn me down after my interview so I'm wary of putting Company A off while waiting for Company B. With my goal being to be as transparent as possible to all parties, here are my questions:

1. How do I communicate to Company B that I don't have an offer but that company B wants to make an offer if at all?
2. What is appropriate to expect as far as decision time-tables and interest level from Company B to inform my decision about Company A?
3. How do I communicate with Company A so that Company B has time to get back to me about their level of interest without alienating Company A?

Comment: P.S. I'm looking for better question titles and I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @Jay, thanks. I actually wasn't sure how to search for my issue here on stackexchange and came up empty with what I tried. That actually does a good job answering my question. To any Mods, what should I do with this question?

Comment: You can leave your question be. No need to delete it, as it will help future users that find your phrasing by linking to the target dupe :) as a side tip, you might want to try your searching on SE network by using *tags*, and then refining the search with keywords (as you can see, the search engine is not the best there is...). I have found that using tags helps to surf better

Answer (score -2):

This is a fairly common situation. Most people will have multiple job applications on the go at once, so it's no problem to tell them that you have other opportunities that you will hear back about soon and that you wish to contemplate all of them before making a decision.

After all, they would obviously want to interview multiple candidates and select the best one, not just the first one who met expectations.

Comment: I don't see how this answers any of the questions OP wrote, this just restates things OP said (like being transparent about his options to everyone)